# xlWings returning String to a function

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

Can xlWings return a string instead a 2dim array in VBA? The documentation hints as if this might be possible, but with the lack of an example, it is hard for me to be certain.

Comment: as of v0.11.8 it always returns a 2dim array but it looks like this is going to change in one of the next releases, so stay tuned.

Comment: Thanks Felix - will be looking forward to some future updates then!